# Email delivery time

Tags: marketing-cloud

We fire an E-Mail in Journey Builder through API event right after entry, this usually take between 1-2 minutes even when email priority is set to high. Are there any settings to deliver the mail instantly without delays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No

**Explanation:** 
The system also takes time to get its act together. Things rarely happen real time as it's goes through SFMC's [Outbound Mail Messaging](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/what_happens_when_you_click_send/) Pathway .

Delivery times are also impacted by the recipient's server (i.e depending on their network and their own "inbound mail mechanism" ) it might take longer for an email to be delivered.

You can help the system out by giving it less to process in your email.

You can do this by;

- not using SSJS
- Reducing API calls within your emails
- only using HTTP functions when necessary
- not using content syndication

Thanks to [AnonWonder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/22717/anonwonderer) for pointing out that wait time are not automatic and [Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) for pointing out latency on the recipient's side.

Comment: Wait periods in Journey Builder can be removed (except for the final one in a path) - are you saying there is a hidden wait period of one minute between each activity?

Comment: OMG you are right. Never knew that. I always added activities after the "final wait" and assumed it was the first one.

Comment: Keep learning will update answer.

Comment: Also be aware that the receiving server can delay delivery too if volume is too high. Although rare, it can actually take up to 48 hours for an email to arrive in the inbox even though it was 'delivered' by sending server.

Comment: Good point will add that to answer